# Remove key icon from the default Browser(

Tags: android, html5-video

Is there a way to remove the key icon(looks like a squareish key) from the default Browser(not chrome) in Android when playing html5 video?

Using this markup:

```
<video id="first-video" preload>
    <source src="video/my-vid.webmvp8.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8,vorbis"' />
    <source src="video/my-vid.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora,vorbis"' /> 
    <source src="video/my-vid.mp4.mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a key icon, it's the bottom right corner of a movie icon. Only happens on some devices, the same video plays great on most others.